# I am trying to learn statement coverage analysis

Tags: code-coverage, code-analysis, software-quality, white-box-testing

I am trying to learn code coverage analysis; I am bit confused because the following code has loops.

Example if the code like this

```
read a;
read b;
i=0
if a>b
while(to i<a)
print(i)
i++;
end while
else
while(to i<b)
print(i)
i++;
end while
end if;
```

what is the percentage of statement coverage if a = 5 and b =7 ?

Comment: Could you expand a little on what you're asking?

Comment: What do you mean *"how to do"*? Are you trying to write a code coverage tool? Configure one? Read the results from one? Change your code according to those results? Give the *context*, what's the *problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: hello thank you for replying i edited the question